# How to forward an iterator?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got this little class:

```
class FreqDict<K> {
    private readonly map: Map<K,number>

    constructor() {
        this.map = new Map;
    }

    inc(key: K): void {
        const n = this.map.get(key);
        this.map.set(key, n ? n+1 : 1);
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for(const item of this.map) {
            yield item;
        }
    }

    entries() {
        return Array.from(this.map.entries())
    }
}
```

You can see how I've implemented the iterator, and that works fine, but `this.map` already has an iterator. Can't I just return/forward it? I'm not sure what the proper syntax is. `return this.map[Symbol.iterator]` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `yield *` syntax to delegate to the `Map` object's own iterator.

As per MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*):

> The `yield*` expression is used to delegate to another generator or
>   iterable object.

In the example snippet below I am delegating to the iterator of the `map` using `yield*` syntax as `Map` is an `Iterable` type:

```js
class FreqDict {
    constructor() {
        this.map = new Map();
    }
    inc(key) {
        const n = this.map.get(key);
        this.map.set(key, n ? n+1 : 1);
    }
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield* this.map;
    }
    entries() {
        return Array.from(this.map.entries())
    }
}
const dict = new FreqDict();
dict.inc("a");
dict.inc("a");
dict.inc("a");
dict.inc("b");
dict.inc("b");

for (const [key, freq] of dict){
  console.log(key, "::", freq);
}
```